# Add tasks for Reviewing tags

Tags: feature-request, review, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

Tag editing is neglected due to lack of visibility. Here are a few review tasks which may help:

- Pending tag synonyms
- Tags with no excerpts
- Tags with no wikis

Comment: I strongly support all three suggested review tasks! I was just looking whether there already exists a request for them, otherwise I had created it... All three would help a lot to improve the quality of our sites!